Angular Unit Tests error : "An error was thrown in afterAll"
While running unit tests in my angular application, i am getting this error in all spec files
"An error was thrown in afterAll
TypeError: Cannot set property HlsHandler of function ir(e,t,i){if(r=ir.getPlayer(e))return t&&h.warn('Player "'+e+'" is already initialised. Options will n......r} which has only a getter".
Has anyone encountered this issue ?
My angular version is 8.2.14, node is 14.15
I think it has something to do with video.js package which is 7.21.5 in my case.

please share the minimal reproducible code

additionally post more of the stack trace of the error. Somewhere is a broke afterAll call
